# WAP Colored Images

Tags: image, colors, wap, wml

I'm beginning with WML development, but I hate that the only option that we have for images are the `WBMP` format, that is only grayscale, then I want to know if there is any way to have colored images using WAP 1.x(not the new 2.x versions of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard colour image formats such as BMP, PNG, JPEG, GIF and animated GIF were supported in the Openwave browsers (certainly Openwave Mobile Browser v6), which were shipped on a huge number of WAP mobile phones. I think it a reasonable assumption that other WAP browsers have similar support.

Beware that some browsers may not support certain advanced features of these formats e.g. progressive display/download in GIF, PNG and JPEG.

So you should be able to do e.g.:

```
<img alt="text" src="url" />
```

where the URL specifies a BMP, PNG, JPEG, GIF, animated GIF etc.

The Openwave browsers also allowed `img` elements within `do` and `option` elements as a non-standard extension to WML.